# Vscode not working with Sailsjs Services and typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, service, visual-studio-code, sails.js

I've have a problem with typescript in a sailsjs app.

I'm using typescript to write my controller, and I want to use sailsjs services inside my controllers but I get a syntax error in VSCODE.

MyController.ts

```
import util = require('util');
import express = require('express');

declare var sails: any;

var count : number = 0;

export function stats(req:any, res:any, next: Function):any {
  console.log('TsController.ts');
  TestLog.send();

  res.status(200).send({});
}
```

TestLog.js

```
module.exports = {
    send: function(){
      console.log("Service is Logging")
    }
  }
```

But VSCODE raise an error

> [ts] Cannot find name 'TestLog'.

By the way if I lift the application is working as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because TypeScript doesn't know that you have a `TestLog` - it is defined in a JavaScript file and isn't imported.

Your "MVP" fix for this is to tell the compiler not to worry about it:

```
declare var TestLog: any;
```

You can then [refine this definition](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2013/01/complex-typescript-definitions-made-easy/) to make it more useful...

```
declare var TestLog: { send(): void };
```

Comment: > It is because TypeScript doesn't know that you have a TestLog - it is defined in a JavaScript file and isn't imported.

There is any way to make the service definition globally available? 

Is not mandatory to have TestLog written in plain javascript

Since I don't want to use something like this

   import { send } from '../../services/TestLog';